# shell script to create text using data

Tags: bash, shell

I have one file that contains data like this

```
User= yojpackco
Domains=yojpack.com


User= yugmaimpre
Domains=yugmaimpressions.com


User= yvmarathej
Domains=yvmarathejewellers.com


User= zawargauge
Domains=zawargauges.com


User= zealservi
Domains=zeal-services.com


User= zenithwor
Domains=zenith-worldwide.com
```

I want to create a txt like this using the first data where domains will replace actual URL and user will replace User FROM ABOVE

```
echo 'Sitemap: https://Domains/sitemap.xml' | tee -a /home/User/public_html/robots.txt >/dev/null

echo 'Sitemap: https://yojpack.com/sitemap.xml' | tee -a /home/yojpackco/public_html/robots.txt >/dev/null
echo 'Sitemap: https://yugmaimpressions.com/sitemap.xml' | tee -a /home/yugmaimpre/public_html/robots.txt >/dev/null
echo 'Sitemap: https://yvmarathejewellers.com/sitemap.xml' | tee -a /home/zawargauge/public_html/robots.txt >/dev/null
echo 'Sitemap: https://zawargauges.com/sitemap.xml' | tee -a /home/zealservi/public_html/robots.txt >/dev/null
echo 'Sitemap: https://zenith-worldwide.com/sitemap.xml' | tee -a /home/zenithwor/public_html/robots.txt >/dev/null
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! This is a site for asking about [specific problems encountered while programming](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). If you would instead like someone to write you some software according to your specifications, please try a freelancing site instead.

Comment: instead of `echo ... | tee -a ..>/dev/null` you can just do `echo ... >> file`

Comment: Why is there a space in `User= xxx` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
while read -r user domain; do 
  echo "echo "Sitemap: https://${domain}/sitemap.xml"  | tee -a /home/"${user}"/public_html/robots.txt" 
done < <(sed -E 's/^.*=[ ]?//;/^ *$/d' INPUT_FILE|paste - -)
# echo output
echo Sitemap: https://yojpack.com/sitemap.xml  | tee -a /home/yojpackco/public_html/robots.txt
echo Sitemap: https://yugmaimpressions.com/sitemap.xml  | tee -a /home/yugmaimpre/public_html/robots.txt
echo Sitemap: https://yvmarathejewellers.com/sitemap.xml  | tee -a /home/yvmarathej/public_html/robots.txt
echo Sitemap: https://zawargauges.com/sitemap.xml  | tee -a /home/zawargauge/public_html/robots.txt
echo Sitemap: https://zeal-services.com/sitemap.xml  | tee -a /home/zealservi/public_html/robots.txt
echo Sitemap: https://zenith-worldwide.com/sitemap.xml  | tee -a /home/zenithwor/public_html/robots.txt
```

Comment: rep2.sh: line 5: syntax error near unexpected token `<'
rep2.sh: line 5: `done < <(sed '/^$/d; s/^.*=//; s/ //g' INPUT_FILE|sed 'N;s/\n/ /')'

Comment: @Bumkailashkumar changed to `< <(sed -E 's/^.*=[ ]?//;/^ *$/d' INPUT_FILE|paste - -)`